# How to get a value from a date from a table with date range?

Tags: c#

I have a table with the value of a range of dates. If I input a date then it should look that date within a date range in the table and give me a value. I am working in C#.

```
DateFrm   |DateTo    |ivalue
----------|----------|-----
2019-01-01|2019-02-01|10
2019-02-02|2019-03-01|11
2019-03-02|2019-04-01|12
```

If I enter a date e.g. 2019-02-09 then it should return me value 11. Please help me to find my values in C#. Thank you.

I was trying something like.. but never get it sorted.

`if(obj.mytable.rows.count>0)`
`{foreach }`
`...`

Comment: You can use query to fetch the data between two dates like SELECT * FROM tablename
WHERE datecolumn >= '"+txtDateFrom.Text+"'  AND datecolumn <=  '"+txtDateTo.Text+"'

Comment: @KinjalGor Ah, going down the SQL injection route?

Comment: What's the type of this table? a DataTable?

Comment: I think I did. I am new here. Let me know if it does not show that, one of the answers accepted.

Comment: @AfzalHossain you should pick the most good answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite simple using LINQ.

```
void Main()
{
    var lst= new List<DateRange>();
    var dr = new DateRange(new DateTime(2019, 1, 1),new DateTime(2019, 2, 1),10);
    lst.Add(dr);
    dr = new DateRange(new DateTime(2019, 2, 2), new DateTime(2019, 3, 1), 11);
    lst.Add(dr);
    dr = new DateRange(new DateTime(2019, 3, 2), new DateTime(2019, 4, 1), 12);
    lst.Add(dr);

    var searchFor = new DateTime(2019, 2, 9);

    var res = (from x in lst
              where x.DateFrm <= searchFor
                 && searchFor <= x.DateTo
             select x.IValue).Single();
    Console.WriteLine($"result:{res}");
}

public class DateRange
{
    public DateTime DateFrm { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTo  { get; set; }
    public int      IValue  { get; set; }
    public DateRange(DateTime dateFrm, DateTime dateTo, int iValue)
    {
        DateFrm = dateFrm;
        DateTo  = dateTo;
        IValue  = iValue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that `dt` is your DataTable:

```
string example = "2019-02-09";
DataRow[] results = dt.Select($"DateFrm <= #{example}# AND DateTo >=#{example}#");
Console.WriteLine(results[0]["ivalue"]);
```

Output:

> 11

Answer (score 1):

Run a loop for the rows to check the condition as specified below

```
  for (int i1 = 0; i1 < table.Rows.Count; i1++)
            {
                DataRow row = table.Rows[i1];
                var datefrm = DateTime.Parse(row["DateFrm"].ToString());
                var dateto = DateTime.Parse(row["DateTo"].ToString());
                if (inputDate >= datefrm && inputDate <= dateto)
                {
                    return row["ivalue"];
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could query your `DataTable` with LINQ, using the extension method [`AsEnumerable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatableextensions.asenumerable). To use this method, a reference to the `System.Data.DataSetExtensions` assembly is required.

```
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("DateFrm", typeof(DateTime));
dt.Columns.Add("DateTo", typeof(DateTime));
dt.Columns.Add("ivalue", typeof(int));
dt.Rows.Add("2019-01-01", "2019-02-01", 10);
dt.Rows.Add("2019-02-01", "2019-03-01", 11);
dt.Rows.Add("2019-03-01", "2019-04-01", 12);

var searchFor = new DateTime(2019, 2, 9);

DataRow[] results = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(row =>
    searchFor >= row.Field<DateTime>("DateFrm") &&
    searchFor < row.Field<DateTime>("DateTo")).ToArray();

foreach (var result in results)
    Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", result.ItemArray));
```

Output:

> 02/02/2019 00:00:00, 03/01/2019 00:00:00, 11

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry that I couldn't make my question easier, potentially I haven't mentioned about I am using LINQ.

I have created a procedure after getting help from here.

```
where DateFrm<=mysearchdate and DateTo<=mysearchdate
```

Later in the flow, I have called that in the code

```
var vl = (from s in obj.st_getiValueSearch(mysearchdate.Value) select s.ivalue).Single();
```

Thanks again for prompt help.